# How to use Devexpress report in Asp.Net MVC 4 Web Application(Not DXperience v12.2 ASP.NET MVC Web Application )

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress

I want to use **Devexpress 12.2 xtrareport** in **Asp.Net MVC 4 Web Application**.Now i think you will suggest me [Create an ASP.NET MVC Application and Add a Report to It](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument9974) but in this they are using **DXperience v12.2 ASP.NET MVC Web Application** and i am using **Asp.Net MVC 4 Web Application**.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution which i find out :

1.)Please review the How to: Manually Register DevExpress Extensions to Start Using Them in an MVC Web Application documentation article to learn how to [register DevExpress ASP.NET MVC extensions manually](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument8163).

2.)This way, you will be able to create a reporting application using the approach from the
[Create a Basic Report in ASP.NET MVC documentation article.](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument9974)